# I dont understand why skimage wont import an image with skimage.io.imread( with a mrcnn model

Tags: python, module, scikit-image

Trying to learn masked cnn under mrcnn using this resource: https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-train-an-object-detection-model-with-keras/

When I try to submit an image to be processed after training I get the following:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-35c42e74a302> in <module>()
     88 image_id = 11
     89 # load the image
---> 90 image = train_set.load_image(image_id)
     91 # load the masks and the class ids
     92 mask, class_ids = train_set.load_mask(image_id)

C:\Users\xxx\anaconda3\envs\vc\lib\site-packages\mrcnn\utils.py in load_image(self, image_id)
    366         """
    367         # Load image
--> 368         image = skimage.io.imread(self.image_info[image_id]['path'])
    369         # If grayscale. Convert to RGB for consistency.
    370         if image.ndim != 3:

AttributeError: module 'skimage' has no attribute 'io'
```

In the code titled untils.py the skimage.io is imported as "import skimage.io", but it seems like another package has hijacked skimage.

Comment: That is really weird.  I would try to force reinstall skimage: `conda install -n vc scikit-image --force-reinstall`,  It may be working looking at a different version of skimage to install as well.  You may have found a bad build.

Comment: maybe you have file `skimage.py` or subfolder `skimage` and `import` loads your file/folder instead of module `skimage` - and it can't find `io` in your file/folder. Renames file/folder.